# pg_restore error: Extensions installed out of sequence

Tags: plpgsql, postgresql-9.5, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a PostgreSQL 9.5 server with the pg_cron extension installed. I'm creating a backup of a database named `testdb` using the command:

```
$ pg_dump -c -U postgres -Fc -f test.dump testdb
```

When I attempt to restore the database on a clean PostgreSQL 9.5 with `pg_cron` already installed via yum, I'm seeing error messages that the `pg_cron` extension could not be installed because the `plpgsql` extension does not exist:

```
$ pg_restore -Fc -d testdb -c -U postgres test.dump
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4; 3079 18235 EXTENSION pg_cron
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  extension "pg_cron" does not exist
    Command was: DROP EXTENSION pg_cron;

pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  language "plpgsql" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.
    Command was: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_cron WITH SCHEMA testschema;

pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3795; 0 0 COMMENT EXTENSION pg_cron
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  extension "pg_cron" does not exist
    Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION pg_cron IS 'Job scheduler for PostgreSQL';

pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3537; 0 18239 TABLE DATA job postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "job" does not exist
    Command was: COPY job  FROM stdin;

WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 4
```

While looking at text output from pg_dump, I noticed the `CREATE EXTENSION` commands are out of order--the file attempts to install `pg_cron` prior to installing `plpgsql`:

```
DROP EXTENSION plpgsql;
DROP EXTENSION pg_cron;
-- Name: pg_cron; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_cron WITH SCHEMA testschema;
-- Name: EXTENSION pg_cron; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner:
COMMENT ON EXTENSION pg_cron IS 'Job scheduler for PostgreSQL';
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner:
COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';
```

Is there a way to force pg_dump to ensure the `CREATE EXTENSION` commands are saved in the proper order?  Do I need to change my backup process to create a backup per schema and always restore `pg_catalog` first?